# Inserting multiple entries into SQL on Flask site

Tags: python, sql, flask

I am quite new to programming and currently I am learning Python and Flask and trying to build a quiz web application as starting/learning project. I want to have an admin side, where I can create/build the quizes.

I am still at the very beginning of the project and most of the stuff are only on paper yet as I am trying to figure out what and how should be done.

My problem started when I was trying to figure out how to insert the possible answers for a question into a table. I have created three classes, that can be used: Quiz, Question and Answer. Obviously once in the database a Quiz can have multiple Questions, which can have multiple Answers (some of which will be correct) - maybe I overcomplicated it, but that's not why I am here.

So when I want to create a Quiz I will need to add multiple entries to the tables at the same time. If I have four input fields for the answers, which are all Answer objects, how can I insert them into the answer table all at once, when clicking the submit button?

It might be something very easy, but I have been thinking about this for a while now and can't figure out. I hope I could write it down in an understandable form.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your models something like the following should work. There would have to be a model for Answer, Question and Quiz with the correct relationships between them. I haven't built in the correct-answer part, but I'm sure you can work that out.

```
# assuming there is a list or dict with your answers
list_of_answers = []
for a in answers:
    list_of_answers.append(Answer(answer = a))

question = Question(question = question, answers = list_of_answers)

quiz = Quiz(name = name, questions = question)

db.session.add(quiz)
db.session.commit()
```

To add multiple questions at once, add a loop on your question objects and use this instead

```
quiz.questions.append(question)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did a less elegant solution, but I will probably try to implement something similar to this.